# Rails: ActionController::ParameterMissing param is missing or the value is empty:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to create a new listing and I can't figure out where is issue is.

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in BusinessListingsController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: businesslisting
```

Below is the code for business_listing_controller:

```
class BusinessListingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @businesslistings = BusinessListing.all
  end

 def new
   @businesslisting = BusinessListing.new
 end

def create
  @businesslisting = BusinessListing.new(businesslisting_params)
  if @businesslisting.save
  redirect_to @businesslisting
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end

def show
  @businesslisting = BusinessListing.find(params[:id])
end

private 
  def businesslisting_params
    params.require(:businesslisting).permit(:title, :price, :city,    :industry)
  end
end
```

**view/business_listing/:**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <%= form_for(@businesslisting) do |f| %>

<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>

<%= f.label :price %>
<%= f.text_field :price %>

<%= f.label :city %>
<%= f.text_field :city %>

<%= f.label :industry %>
<%= f.text_field :industry %>

<%= f.submit "Create a Listing", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you paste a trace of your params as outputted on the console during the create action?

Comment: Try to restart your server & then try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not following Rails naming conventions.  You have your class as `BusinessListing`, but you are naming instance variables and param references as `businesslisting`.  `BusinessListing` (camel case) is essentially two words, which should be matched as snake case when using instance variable names: `business_listing`

The same would go for your param name.  [When you pass a model object into `form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-23form_for+with+a+model+object), Rails uses the class name to determine the param name, so I'll bet the actual param that's coming across is `business_listing`, not `businesslisting`

Just change all occurrences of `businesslisting` to `business_listing` (and `businesslistings` to `business_listings`) throughout your code, and you should no longer experience this issue.

The most important change would be here:

```
params.require(:business_listing).permit(:title, :price, :city, :industry)
```

This by itself should solve your current issue, but I strongly encourage you to follow the convention throughout your code to avoid further issue and confusion.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3):

I had this challenge when working on a **Rails 6** API in **Ubuntu 20.04**.

I had a `Schools` Resource (Controller, Model and Route) and I needed to create a School using Postman. The `Schools` resource has 2 params (name and alias). So I used the **Params** section to pass it, but I get the error:

```
app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:49:in `school_params'
app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:18:in `create'
Started POST "/schools" for ::1 at 2020-12-09 03:40:29 +0100
Processing by SchoolsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"name"=>"The Prince School", "alias"=>"The Prince"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 122)
  
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: school):
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that the application was expecting another parameter called `school` which will encapsulate other parameters, according to my `school_params` in the `SchoolsController`:

```
def school_params
  params.require(:school).permit(:name, :alias)
end
```

**Solution 1**:

I defined the `Content-Type` as `application/json` in the **Header** section, then passed the parameters in the **Body** section of Postman as **raw** JSON object using this:

```
{
    "school": {
        "name": "The Prince School",
        "alias": "The Prince"
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

And it worked fine.

**Solution 2**:

I submitted the request using form-data by clicking on the **Body** section of Postman and selecting **form-data**. SO the request looked this way:

```
school[name]:The Prince School
school[alias]:The Prince
```

[image]

**Resources**: [Testing Rails 5 API with Postman](https://medium.com/@spaquet/testing-rails-5-api-with-postman-36f1e79dc4d#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImQ0Y2JhMjVlNTYzNjYwYTkwMDlkODIwYTFjMDIwMjIwNzA1NzRlODIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.kVdU7BdpjEFIT0Ivee47y5O1b4rvikzrcgwqXc8YEIe8-EG5Zw3PTh34Eecu3FI4dh8bz34xXfH8bZAMf0-BLCQBrJYWakHtNZXyhhd9iNt4tUoNgk55APby2EBn9eh4XsgG-CVUC5_280JQpZ3eKUiK0K57CwYhvPC7FsBUyvbaYiC8ZBTtab3vsIZMHPscKlZnh-vz4lEm6rwvNPY-Spyq-zw1m0yYZw4_V8LKh3-ocw6fZODDXFmX68anTNot3nY0bOFeT2TmKyc0h1MXaZcUKULY6UtAe3adR7aqGwOn8bZpPr2fBvhsIPNgY6zHDGm3OdbBqtbxgycymeSUVg)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**